# php , mysql not allowed to connect to static function

Tags: php, mysql, permissions

I have a strange problem and not satisfied with the resolution i got from my webhost.

firstly i have backend system which runs php and was working fine till today.
the system stopped adding some info to the mysql db , and upon investigation , i found that 
it was not running a static function which is was calling .

the server log error :

> [25-Nov-2013 13:34:31 Africa/Johannesburg] PHP Warning: mysqli::mysqli() [mysqli.mysqli]: (HY000/1130): Host '197.242.74.19' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server in /home/chamdorf/public_html/testsite/libs/config.php on line 72
>
> [25-Nov-2013 13:34:31 Africa/Johannesburg] PHP Warning: mysqli::query() [mysqli.query]: Couldn't fetch mysqli in /home/chamdorf/public_html/testsite/rwdsa/catalogue/mptt.php on line 137
>
> [25-Nov-2013 13:34:31 Africa/Johannesburg] PHP Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on a non-object in /home/chamdorf/public_html/testsite/rwdsa/catalogue/mptt.php on line 139

funny part is this was working perfectly fine . 
wokrking with webhost , we changed in my connection string from chamdorfaktrysales.co.za
to localhost and now it works fine .

with the host as chamdorfaktrysales.co.za , the site works fine only gives and error when i do this :

its mvc so this is basically the page im calling

```
function rebuild_tree()
    {
                  mptt::rebuild_tree('1',1);      

        return  $this->Data;    
    }

static function rebuild_tree($parent_id, $left) {

         //init and get db connection from self
           $a = new mptt();
           $db = $a->DBopen;


           // the right value of this node is the left value + 1
           $right = $left+1;   

           // get all children of this node
            $query_node = $db->query("SELECT CategoryID FROM categories 
                              WHERE ParentID = '$parent_id' ");   

           while ($row = $query_node->fetch_assoc()) {
               // recursive execution of this function for each
               // child of this node
               // $right is the current right value, which is
               // incremented by the rebuild_tree function
               $right = mptt::rebuild_tree($row['CategoryID'], $right);
           }   

           // we've got the left value, and now that we've processed
       // the children of this node we also know the right value
       $db->query("UPDATE categories SET lft='$left', rgt='$right' 
               WHERE CategoryID='$parent_id' ");   

           // return the right value of this node + 1
           return $right+1;
        }
```

any ideas on what the issue could be ? 
Webhost might have made changes ?
any help , ideas appreciated , Thanks

Comment: I don't see why this method should be static. However, this error sould be enough `Host '197.242.74.19' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL serve`

Comment: Your server log `Host '197.242.74.19' is not allowed to connect` is just pointing to a simple MySQL permission setting. And you say that when you changed your connection to `localhost` it works fine. So what exactly is the problem?

Comment: Hi , its stored in a separate file , which is not in my current view

Comment: @jszobody , the problem is what if i load the site on a different domain , and i need to connect to the db . i cant use locahost then.
Also , using chamdorfaktrysales.co.za works fine on the rest of the system , only gives a problem when calling the static function

Answer (score 0):

Check in your my.cnf if the bind-address is configured correctly, this link might help:

http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/unix-linux-mysqld-server-bind-to-more-than-one-ip-address/

Answer (score 0):

It's working again like it was , an this is what the web host said when i emailed them,
which i find hard to believe .

There were no changes on our side made to the server. You can see MySQL has not been restarted at all, same version with same permissions.

I've had issues before when using the domain name as the MySQL host, common practice always refers to localhost.